# Visual Studio 2005 Build of Python with Debug .lib

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I am looking for the Visual Studio 2005 build of Python 2.4, 2.5 or 2.6, I also need the python2x_d.lib (the debug version of the .lib) since I embed the interpreter into my app and the python libs implicitly link to the python2x_d.lib with pragmas (grrr).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you [download the Python source](http://python.org/download/) (tgz and tar.bz2 zipped versions available) and compile it yourself.  It comes with a VS2005 solution so it isn't difficult.  I had to do this for a SWIG project I was working on.

Answer (score 0):

If you have trouble finding the debug builds, you can try and build your own. Browse the [build directory](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/PCbuild/), for project files like `python.vcproj` - to locate versions that will work with Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 0):

I recall, some time ago, giving IronPython a 'whirl' in VS2005. I ran into all kinds of 'esoteric' errors until I figured out that to compile and run I had to add the C++ libraries and tools of VS2005 as well (add/remove).
Maybe this is something similar ?